# How to do if/else statement for fileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

Heyy all. I am trying to do an if/else statement for my fileupload function on my Edit Profile page in my ASP.net webpage.

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Declaration of variable to update Profile Image
    string imageName, newContact;
    imageName = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();
    newContact = tbMobile.Text.ToString();

    username = (String)Session["NonAdmin"];
    MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("server=182.50.133.91;user id=Jonathan;password=jon123;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=ajactrac_;allowuservariables=True");
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from pointofcontact where Username = '" + username.ToString() + "'", mcon);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    if (dt.Rows.Count.ToString() == "1")
    {

        MySqlCommand command = mcon.CreateCommand();
        MySqlCommand command1 = mcon.CreateCommand();
        MySqlCommand command2 = mcon.CreateCommand();
        MySqlCommand command3 = mcon.CreateCommand();
        MySqlCommand command4 = mcon.CreateCommand();
        MySqlCommand command5 = mcon.CreateCommand();
        MySqlCommand command6 = mcon.CreateCommand();
        MySqlCommand command7 = mcon.CreateCommand();

        command.CommandText = "update pointofcontact set Password = ?pwd where Username = '" + username.ToString() + "'";
        command1.CommandText = "update pointofcontact set FirstName = ?firstname where Username = '" + username.ToString() + "'";
        command2.CommandText = "update pointofcontact set LastName = ?lastname where Username = '" + username.ToString() + "'";
        command3.CommandText = "update pointofcontact set ContactNumber = ?contact where Username = '" + username.ToString() + "'";
        command4.CommandText = "update pointofcontact set EmailAddress = ?email where Username = '" + username.ToString() + "'";
        command5.CommandText = "update pointofcontact set Address = ?address where Username = '" + username.ToString() + "'";
        command6.CommandText = "update pointofcontact set BackupContactNumber = ?backupnumber where Username = '" + username.ToString() + "'";
        command7.CommandText = "update pointofcontact set ProfilePic = ?newimage where Username = '" + username.ToString() + "'";

        mcon.Open();
        if (tbNewPassword.Text == "")
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?pwd", tbOldPassword.Text.Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?pwd", tbNewPassword.Text.Trim());
        }

        if(tbNewFirstName.Text == "")
        {
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?firstname", tbFirstName.Text.Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("?firstname", tbNewFirstName.Text.Trim());
        }

        if(tbNewLastName.Text == "")
        {
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?lastname", tbLastName.Text.Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("?lastname", tbNewLastName.Text.Trim());
        }

        if(tbNewContact.Text == "")
        {
            command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("?contact", tbMobile.Text.Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            command3.Parameters.AddWithValue("?contact", tbNewContact.Text.Trim());
        }

        if(tbNewEmail.Text == "")
        {
            command4.Parameters.AddWithValue("?email", tbEmail.Text.Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            command4.Parameters.AddWithValue("?email", tbNewEmail.Text.Trim());
        }

        if(tbNewAddress.Text == "")
        {
            command5.Parameters.AddWithValue("?address", tbAddress.Text.Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            command5.Parameters.AddWithValue("?address", tbNewAddress.Text.Trim());
        }

        if(tbNewBackupContact.Text == "")
        {
            command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("?backupnumber", tbBackupContact.Text.Trim());
        }
        else
        {
            command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("?backupnumber", tbNewBackupContact.Text.Trim());
        }


        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + imageName);
        command7.Parameters.AddWithValue("?newimage", imageName);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command4.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command5.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command6.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command7.ExecuteNonQuery();

        mcon.Close();
        string javaScript = "<script language=JavaScript>\n" + "alert('Profile Updated!');\n" + "</script>";
        RegisterStartupScript("xyz", javaScript);
    }
    else
    {
        string javaScript = "<script language=JavaScript>\n" + "alert('Some Error Occured! Profile Not Updated!');\n" + "</script>";
        RegisterStartupScript("xyz", javaScript);
    }
    tbNewPassword.Text = "";




}
```

I had planned to use the if else statement for my fileupload function such that if the user has not uploaded a new picture, he/she would be still able to update their profile.

Currently when I try to edit a user's profile, this error message comes out.

Comment: I am also currently using a MySQL Database.

Comment: do u have this path in your workspace   `C:\Users\stutt\Desktop\AJACTRACWebsite\AJACTRACWebsite\Images\`

Comment: I have checked the folder and the file path is the same as whats stated in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Before uploading files to any directory, it is good to have this statement before saving file.

```
if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Images")))
            Directory.CreateDirectory("~/Images");
```

add above statement before this line

```
 FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Images", imageName)));
```

Comment: I am getting error messages saying that "The name 'Directory' does not exist in the current context". 

Any idea on how to go about fixing the error?

Comment: add this namespace `using System.IO`